# Remove unchecked checkbox from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of checkboxes:

```
<div id="other-products">
  <input type="checkbox" name="First" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Second" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Third" value="3">
</div>
<span class="list-products"></span>
```

JS code like this, which generates all the names of the checked inputs.

```
$('#other-products').on('change', function() {
    var selectedProducts = [];
    $('#other-products input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
      selectedProducts.push($(this).attr('name'));
      var showtimesAsString = selectedProducts.join(', ');
      $('.list-products').html(showtimesAsString);
    });
});
```

The problem is, when I select few checkboxes, then unselect all of them, last unselected checkbox title is shown in .list-products. Any ideas why it is not empty? Thanks!

Comment: When you uncheck the last checkbox, there is no checked item and so the each loop will not execute.

Comment: From http://api.jquery.com/change - "This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resetting the html content of the list-products outside of the loop.

https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/188/

```
 $('#other-products').on('change', function() {
    var selectedProducts = [];
    var listProductsCtrl = $('.list-products');
    listProductsCtrl.html(''); //reset the values here
    $('#other-products input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
      selectedProducts.push($(this).attr('name'));
      var showtimesAsString = selectedProducts.join(', ');
      listProductsCtrl.html(showtimesAsString);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to causing your script to not work as intended, setting `showtimesAsString` in `$.each` in inefficient. Move the 2 lines where you create the string and set the `.html()` outside of `$.each()`.

```js
$('#other-products').on('change', function() {
  var selectedProducts = [];

  $('#other-products input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    selectedProducts.push($(this).attr('name'));

  });

  var showtimesAsString = selectedProducts.join(', ');
  $('.list-products').html(showtimesAsString);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="other-products">
  <input type="checkbox" name="First" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Second" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Third" value="3">
</div>
<span class="list-products"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your code to something like the following:

```
$('#other-products').on('change', function() {
    var selectedProducts = $('#other-products input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    var showtimesAsString = "";

    selectedProducts.each(function() {
       showtimesAsString += $(this).attr("name") + ",";
    });

    $('.list-products').html(showtimesAsString);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5bu0sqjf/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#other-products').on('change', function() {
    var selectedProducts = [];
    $('.list-products').html('');
    $('#other-products input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
      selectedProducts.push($(this).attr('name'));
      var showtimesAsString = selectedProducts.join(', ');
      $('.list-products').html(showtimesAsString);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function to really simplify the code and avoid having to manually reset your array and output string.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#other-products').on('change', function() {
    var names = $('#other-products input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
      return $(this).attr('name');
    }).get();
    $('.list-products').html(names.join(', '));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="other-products">
  <input type="checkbox" name="First" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Second" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Third" value="3">
</div>
<span class="list-products"></span>
```